# cannot acces foreign keys in django

Tags: django, model

I have the following template:

```
{% extends "artdb/base.html" %}

{% block content1 %}
<h4>Persons:</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for p in ans %}
    <h5>First name: {{p.firstName}}</h5>
    <h5>Last name: {{p.lastName}}</h5>
    <h5>Phone: {{p.phoneNumber}}</h5>
    <h5>Adress: {{p.streetAdress}}</h5>
    <h5>Zip Code: {{p.zipcode}}</h5>
    <h5>City: {{p.city}}</h5>
    <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content1 %}

{% block content2 %}
<h4>Roles:</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for p in ans %}
    <h5>Role:{{p.persons.role}}</h5>
    <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content2 %}
```

and the model:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    mail=models.EmailField()
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phoneNumber=PhoneNumberField()
    streetAdress=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Göteborg")
    country=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Sweden")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName,self.lastName)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('firstName','lastName')

class Role(models.Model):

    role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person=models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)
```

But when I run the above code the only output that I get is from the block content1, i.e I cannot access the role content. I thought that role.persons.role would do it but apperantley not. There is a many-to-many relationship between perssons and roles. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What model is `ans`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
{% block content2 %}
    <h4>Roles:</h4>
    <ul>
        {% for p in ans %}
           {% for role in p.role_set.all %}
               <h5>Role:{{ role }}</h5>
               <hr>
           {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content2 %}
```

We have to create a second for loop, since a many to many relationship will always return a list. Not a single instance. So essentially it's just like accessing a 2d array.

In Django you only have to define a n:n relationship on one end. Django will then automatically add it to the other model as well. It does this by taking the related model name and suffixing `_set`. So if we want to reference all of the roles attached to a person, it would be `person.role_set`. The other way around it would be `role.person` like you defined in the model.

Comment: thanks. I tried the above code but with no successm, no output from role. I will look into it further.

Comment: Try something like `{{ p.role_set.all }}`. See if that outputs anything.

Comment: <h5>Test1:{{p.role_set.all}}</h5> gives an empty query. role_set_all returns an empty set

Comment: That's weird. I can't think of any reason that wouldn't work except that maybe you don't have any roles attached to any persons. Does just `{{ p }}` work at all?

Comment: ok, I went into admin and checked relationsships, and yes, I hadn't connected the roles to the persons. now it seems to work. Thanks again.